# What does the phrase "dangling-armed trolls" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a sentence from an adventure game:

> If you are not careful, you might be grabbed by the **dangling-armed
>   trolls** that reach from afar.

The player fights against many creatures, monsters, etc. I am not sure if the "dangling-armed" has any metaphorical meaning here.

Answer (score 4):

Without context I cannot be sure, but I think this is simply a physical description -- these trolls have arms that dangle down.